# Positional argument missing expect [1] but found [0]

Tags: flutter, dart

```
getUserInfo() async {
    Constants.myname = await HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference**(())**;
  }
```

I am getting this error here Please help me

Comment: Please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: Could you please share the signature of the `getUserNameSharedPreference` function?

Comment: static Future<bool> saveUserNameSharedPreference(String userName) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await prefs.setString(sharedPreferenceUserNameKey, userName);
  }

Comment: which positional argument should I add ?

Comment: You need to pass a username to the function. You should probably also take the language tour if you haven't already: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour